# What parametres can i set in sefrom()

Tags: php, web, phpmailer

Hello everyone one I want to know what types of email address can I pass using php function setFrom() if I am only using phpmailer.

Comment: Anything that's valid? You could also try [reading the documentation](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_setFrom) on that function.

Comment: can i use my gmail id here

Comment: It's an email address, so yes, though bear in mind that you must send *through* gmail if you're using a gmail from address, otherwise it's forgery.

Answer (score 0):

```
setFrom('Yourmail@gmail.com','Name to be Displayed');
```

the setFrom email will be the sender address on receiver's mail